# One Catch for all methods inside Try?

Tags: c#, vb.net, try-catch

I have a `Button` that runs three methods when clicked:

```vb
Try
    Label1.Text = "Please wait..."

    RunMethod1()
    RunMethod2()
    RunMethod3()

    Label1.Text = "Success!"
Catch ex As Exception
    Label1.Text = "Something wrong happened!"
End Try
```

Right now, any errors are displayed in the Visual Studio IDE ('Exception was unhandled by user code').  There are no `Try-Catch` blocks inside these three methods.

How do I get the 'Something wrong happened!' displayed in the `Label` whenever an exception occurs within any of the three methods?

Comment: This code must do the work. Do you have any error?. Maybe you could define a variable "msg" to keep text and set the label once on Finally try/catch block

Comment: Your code is correct unless there is something different you want us to do.

Comment: What does it say was unhandled? This should be correct as written.

Comment: First method is actually an asynchronous SQL call and the second is binding the result to the controls.  I just wrote it like that (RunMethod, etc.) because I thought it wouldn't make a difference.. or would it?

Comment: I tested it by wronging the table name at the `CommandText` property.  The code stops and the IDE points the exception to the line of the first method, instead of going to the `Catch` block... :(

Comment: The only thing that would be worth noting is that the message is useless and although friendly to the user, should an error occur you need to spend time debugging to find said error code.

Comment: Have you made sure that you haven't set so that Visual Studio breaks on _every_ exception? Go into the `Debug > Windows` menu and press `Exception Settings`. In the window that opens click the button that says `Restore the list to the default settings` when you hover over it (see [**screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOgpN.jpg)). Then try running your code again.

Answer (score 1):

It's as straight forward as that in C#.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Method1();
            Method2();
            Method3();
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Something wrong happened!");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private static void Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is one");
    }
    private static void Method2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is two");
        string foo = null;
        foo.ToUpper();
    }
    private static void Method3()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is three");
    }
```

Of course replace the console.writeline() with your label.text

Answer (score 1):

**** Use this Code****

```
 try
   {
    Label1.Text = "Please wait...";

    RunMethod1();
    RunMethod2();
    RunMethod3();

    Label1.Text = "Success!";
   }
  catch(Exception ex)
   {
    Label1.Text = "Something wrong happened!";
   }
}

private void RunMethod1()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private void RunMethod2()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private void RunMethod3()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```